# USB wakeup from suspended state on Android 13.x IMX8MQ evk

Tags: kernel, android, suspend, usb-device

I am unable to use USB wake-up feature of Android on IMX8MQ evk.

I am using the following setup:

```
-Imx8mq EVK
-Android 13
-Kernel 5.15.71-dirty
-GSM modem is attached via USB
```

I have set the following configurations in adb shell

```
$echo auto > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/control
$echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup
```

Then I use the following command to suspend the Android

```
$ echo freeze > sys/power/state
```

This makes the Android go to suspended state but  if I send SMS or Call on the modem then Android doesn't wakeup. I have to wake it up using the on/off button on imx8mq board.

The dmesg logs show

```
[ 261.447647] [ T2070] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[ 261.492072] [ T2070] Filesystems sync: 0.039 seconds
[ 261.497027] [ T2070] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
[ 261.508140] [ T2070] OOM killer disabled.
[ 261.512084] [ T2070] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[ 261.527000] [ T2070] [drm] Reg val is 0x0080
[ 261.635878] [ T2070] [drm] hdmi phy shutdown complete
[ 261.688235] [ T143] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
[ 332.909844] [ C0] PM: pm_system_irq_wakeup: 37 triggered 30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey
[ 332.931925] [ T2070] [drm] Pixel clock: 148500 KHz, character clock: 148500, bpc is 8-bit, fmt 1
[ 332.940661] [ T2070] [drm] VCO frequency is 5940000 KHz
[ 332.995653] [ T2070] [drm] Mode: 1920x1080p148500
[ 333.039877] [ T2070] [drm] Pixel clock: 148500 KHz, character clock: 148500, bpc is 8-bit, fmt 1
[ 333.048594] [ T2070] [drm] VCO frequency is 5940000 KHz
[ 333.131966] [ T2070] [drm] No vendor infoframe
[ 333.374189] [ T2070] OOM killer enabled.
[ 333.378069] [ T2070] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 333.386479] [ T2070] Resume caused by IRQ 37, 30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey
[ 333.390998] [ T419] healthd: battery l=85 v=3 t=35.0 h=2 st=2 c=400000 fc=4000000 cc=32 chg=au
[ 333.393671] [ T2070] PM: suspend exit
[ 333.526105] [ T143] android_work: did not send uevent (0 0 0000000000000000)
[ 333.526243] [ T552] read descriptors
[ 333.538834] [ T552] read strings
[ 334.389181] [ T1] init: Untracked pid 2070 exited with status 0
[ 334.396626] [ T1] init: Untracked pid 2070 did not have an associated service entry and will not be reaped
[ 334.498085] [ T20] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
[ 334.649956] [ T20] android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
```

The USB enumeration

```
[ 53.799900] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci-hcd
[ 53.909564] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=1342, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 53.918672] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[ 54.099461] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.107372] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 54.117025] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.125232] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 54.134651] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.142854] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 54.152350] [ T20] option 1-1.3:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 54.160511] [ T20] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[ 54.194934] [ T20] qmi_wwan 1-1.3:1.4: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[ 54.208145] [ T20] qmi_wwan 1-1.3:1.4 wwan0: register 'qmi_wwan' at usb-xhci-hcd.0.auto-1.3, WWAN/QMI device, 02:4f:9d:5b:0b:f3
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong here and how should I investigate the issue.

Comment: Try `echo "on" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/control`. Setting it to auto means, that the device is automatically send to sleep when the OS is suspending. "on" keeps it active, at least if the driver supports all that stuff.